# How to bind individual html lines to multiple labels in xamarin.forms with c#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I've just started using binding so this may simple but I haven't found any suitable answers online. I have the labels

```html
<Label x:DataType="myNameSpace:MyClass" Text = "{Binding label}"/>
<Label x:DataType="myNameSpace:MyClass" Text = "{Binding label2}"/>
```

I need to bind different strings of html from json elements stored in a `dynamic dynamicObject;` to different labels. So I can't just assign the entire view to a label as [Label Class Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label?view=xamarin-forms%5C) suggests. The C# is

```
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = dynamicObject.mainText;
        label.TextType = TextType.Html;
```

However, I need to use xaml and it always says that `label` is not found in the data context MyClass. Even using `public String label{get{return "Text";}}` does not display anything. What is the most efficient way to do access different strings from the object and display them in different labels?

Comment: get rid of the `x:DataType` attribute

Comment: @Jason this does nothing but tells me theres no DataContext for Binding label

Comment: How do you set up your ViewModel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{Binding label}` requires that the `BindingContext` contain a "public property" named `label`.

Do you SET BindingContext anywhere? In view constructor, do

> `BindingContext=new MyClass();`.

... modify as needed, to initialize MyClass with whatever data it should have

---

Then MyClass.cs must look something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // These must be PUBLIC PROPERTIES.
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string label2 { get; set; }
}
```

Usage looks like this:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding label}"/>
<Label Text = "{Binding label2}"/>
```

Note that, as Jason says, there are no `x:DataType` attributes. Those are for a different situation.

---

A common mistake is to not have PROPERTIES.

```
// This won't work. This is a FIELD, not a property.
public string label;
```

---

If you still can't run because of errors that refer to DataContext or DataType, then:

- REMOVE ALL `x:DataType` statements in the xaml file. There is probably one in the first few lines of the XAML.  <-- ONLY REMOVE IF this is preventing the app from building or running successfully. If it isn't causing any fatal problem, leave it there.
- IGNORE (disregard) any DataType/DataContext warning from Intellisense - just run it, and see if it works.

If you get that to work, then it is possible to start adding `x:DataType` statements back in, to eliminate the intellisense warnings. But they don't belong on the individual labels. I consider this an "advanced" topic, and won't say more about it here.